# problem with distributed ROS (swarm of ardrones)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I'm having issues with the control of 3 ardrones, each one connected to its laptop, where one of these laptos is configured as the master.

The network is configured properly.

The first problem occured with 2 drones. When flying togheter, I kept getting the following error "Reconnecting ... Reconnecting ... Timeout when reading navdatas - resending a navdata request on port 5554"

So I firstly switched from the 200 hz of the navdata msgs sent from the drone to 15 hz,
and I set the drone driver loop from 50 to 20. The two drones where then able to fly togheter.
When I added the third, unfortunately, the error reappeared.

In my nodes I write on a custom topic the informations relative to each drone (I send them each 300 ms), I have 2 loops repeating at 200 and 100 ms, and on each laptop two nodes for marker detection (ar_track_alvar package)

Does anyone have an idea of how to make the system work robustly with 3 drones?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61831/problem-with-distributed-ros-(swarm-of-ardrones)/) by [jacky_90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4309/jacky_90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just realised that was wifi's fault. All the 3 drones are using the same channel. I have not find a way to make each drone select a different channel, though.

---

Originally posted by [jacky_90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4309/jacky_90/) with karma: 101 on 2013-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1